# A grey color fill the screen when running the app from the APK file Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

The App is running well in the emulator and the real android device connecting with USB but this error always appear in the console `Note: /home/mohamed/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-2.1.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`

[It shows like that with the error from the APK file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGXsN.jpg)

[It should be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p92f.jpg)

and I have added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the AndroidMainfest.xml but nothing changed...!

any help, please

Comment: The grey screen in release APK's is the equivalent of the red screen in debug mode. So you probably have something that is throwing an error. Are you sure your log isn't showing any errors in debug mode?

Comment: @Roaa First, thanks for your time)  I have updated my question with the error which is appearing in the running or debugging mode

Comment: Are there any exceptions caught in the debug console? If yes then fix those, then it may work

Comment: I have tried to solve it but the issues but all the solution is not fitting me and no change unfortunately..!

Answer (score 0):

While running on debug mode, you see a lot of warnings. Many of those warnings can result in that grey screen on the release build. I suspect that bottom sheet is the main issue here, as we can see the map underneath the greyed out area.

Comment: I thought that the problem was in the bottom sheet too, I have changed the color and the components but nothing changed..!, I have tried to solve the issues shown in the console but unfortunately all the answers is not working with me

Comment: Can you post the warnings shown in the console?